# Does all data flow through haproxy or will it redirect?

Tags: haproxy

If I am using haproxy as my only publicly accessible server that's job is to route requests to our backend servers, will all data flow through the haproxy server?

If we have 50 servers and a single haproxy server, and the actual 1 gigabyte port on our front end haproxy server will not suffice.

If this is the case (which I believe it to be), what options do we have?

I believe I read something about dynamic dns, is that a potential solution?  So clients still reach us at a single i.p address (mapping to our domain name), but once it hits our local network, dynamic dns will round robin (or something smarter) requests to a cluster of haproxy servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, yes. Haproxy will receive all requests and forward them to the appropriate backend server and receives the responses and forwards them back to the clients.

You can use the DNS option you have described, but you need to have multiple IP addresses associated with the domain name. Each IP will be assigned/forwarded to one haproxy instance.

Answer (score 0):

DNS round robin is simple just the domain name have to has multyple A records and this does the thing. But it means multiple public IP adresses.

As all traffic goes through your current HAProxy and 1 gig not enough for you than 10 gig is the solution.

Or maybe combine these solution if you cant afford many public IPs. Have more than one HAProxies and DNS round robin them.